# Levels in NetCDF created in R with raster package are interpreted as time steps - create 4D rasterBrick

Tags: raster, r, netcdf

I can't seem to find a way to create an empty rasterBrick and then create a NetCDF file that has no time axis and only vertical levels. Here's my code

```
mylevels=10
s1 <- brick(nc=180, nr=90,nl=mylevels)
for (i in 1:mylevels) {

    s1[[i]]<-rasterize(... processing....
}

writeRaster(s1,'myfile,nc',format='CDF',varname='var1',varunit='kg')
```

Now when I open the file with any NetCDF software such as CDO or ferret my levels are read as time steps instead of vertical levels. I have tried to use zvar='var1' but it's not working. I am trying to avoid the NetCDF package because my data processing works just fine. I also can't find any information on how to create a rasterBrick with 4 dimensions. Is it possible?

Comment: It's not possible. stars has (more) truly multidimensional rasters, but no helpers for writing NetCDF - you'll have to use RNetCDF or ncdf4.

Comment: @mdsumner That's what I thought, thanks. It's strange that stars doesn't allow to write NetCDF. What's the difference between the two NetCDF packages? I find ncdf4 somewhat clunky for writing/reading, it required more steps compared to raster.

Comment: RNetCDF is probably more likely to be supported in the long run, it's more straightforward for writing (but not easy, there's no model for this data in R that stores all this stuff

Comment: So it's not strange (to me) that stars doesn't do it, there's no existing framework to wrap. There's no model for this data in R that stores all this stuff - stars has a good chance at being that, but it's still a nasty hard thing to generalize to the level that writeRaster can be for 2D grids. In rasters you only really need extent, crs, dimension, and the data. In arrays you need info about everything because it *could be anything*. A bit chicken-egg I think in R.